# Running javascript code with html button

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a JavaScript code that isn't a function. I need to run it with a button. The problem is i can't use `onclick="myfunction()"` because it is not a function. My js file is called "myFunction.js". How do i execute the js code with a html button?

Comment: Why don't use encapsulate your code in a function?

Comment: Include your `myFunction.js` in your file and than invoke function which is needed !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to put the code inside a function in order to make it run when you want. Having the code outside a function would simply run the code as it is loaded. Basically, what you need to do is:

```
    function myFunction(){

        *insert code to execute here*

    }
```

That should do it for you, and just make sure that this is appropriately added to the page (in the header between  tags, or on an external sheet. A good source for this is http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp

Comment: "A good source for this is http://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp" well not really. By the way, you should [read this](http://www.w3fools.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onclick="myFunction()"` in your button.

Add your code into a function (in the file myFunction.js for example) :

```
function myFunction() {
    alert("hello world"); // for example
}
```

To finish, link you js file to your html like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/yourpath/myFunction.js"></script>
```

Put it just before the tag `</body>`.